# 'if' statement only accomplished only once in a loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am simulating a cache system by performing a cumulative sum of bytes and, when this sums up to 0.95 the size of the cache, forces the value to be 0.9 of the full size.

Final result should evolve as a saw tooth.

This is the code I implement to force this condition.

```
cache_size=1e11 #B 
high_mark=0.95
low_mark=0.50
ordered_datestamp['Cache']=0
for i in range(1,rows_number):
    ordered_datestamp['file_size_Cum'][i]=ordered_datestamp['file_size_Cum'][i-1]+ordered_datestamp['file_size'][i]
    ordered_datestamp['Cache'][i]=ordered_datestamp['file_size_Cum'][i]
    if(ordered_datestamp['Cache'][i]>high_mark*cache_size):
        ordered_datestamp['Cache'][i]=low_mark*ordered_datestamp['Cache'][i]
```

And this is the output.

[image: Simulation output]

How does the if statement is only accomplished once in the loop?

Comment: What issue are you facing?

Comment: I am performing a cumulative sum (summing the last element of the dataframe to the next and so on), but with the condition of updating the value of the cumulative sum when it exceeds some value 'cache_size'. Close to 11-19 the value is updated correctly as the loop states, but it is only happening once instead of apply it for the whole evolution (the output should looks a saw tooth shape graph).

Comment: Add some print statements so you see the values you're working with.

Answer (score 0):

Given the code, I don't see why the observed behavior is wrong.
This is how you are capping the cumulative sum:

`ordered_datestamp['Cache'][i]=low_mark*ordered_datestamp['Cache'][i]`

You are scaling the value by `low_mark` factor and not actually capping it. So it is possible that it goes beyond the cache size. You probably intend to do:

`ordered_datestamp['Cache'][i]=low_mark*cache_size`

Also, I don't see where `ordered_datestamp['file_size_Cum'][0]` is initialized. You are initializing `ordered_datestamp['Cache']=0` which is weird as `ordered_datestamp['Cache']` seems to be a list.